What do "religious light" and "youthful features cruelly aged" mean?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

He was a mawkish creature, sudden but without spring, with youthful features cruelly aged and a raw unhealthy rash around his neck where his shirt had scuffed the skin. In the religious light between dawn and morning his black waistcoat and white collar had the glint of the soutane.

What do "religious light" and "youthful features cruelly aged" mean ? Does "religious light" mean this kind of light is often found in a church and does it suggest a sense of solemnity here? And does "youthful features cruelly aged" mean although some of his features still seem young, the whole body is getting old in a cruel way？

I think you are right about 'religious light'. It's a reference to Milton's Il Penseroso in which he describes the atmosphere in a church, with "storied windows richly dight [stained glass windows] casting a dim religious light".

"Cruelly aged" would seem to simply be a reference to someone who appears to be older than they actually are. You see this sometimes in people who've lead hard lives, or who work outdoors a lot, or in some cases it's an unfortunate accident of genetics. We can infer this from the inclusion of "youthful features" which indicate that aspects of Lacon's face still retain some signs of a younger man - we might imagine chubby cheeks or large eyes - but over which wrinkles, furrows and other signs of age have been written by the passage of time.
I do not believe this line is supposed to pertain to the rest of Lacon's body. After all, Smiley does not get to see it and most people observing another do not go on to imagine them partially or fully naked.
"Religious light" is less certain but, for me, it conjures up the image of a single beam of illumination picking out a feature in a church or religious artefact. So, yes, it is related to the kind of light found in churches. Places of worship are often built in such a way that beams of light from small windows fall onto objects of particular beauty or significance. It's not hard to imagine early morning light, just as the sun is rising, achieving this effect as the first rays of sun over the horizon tend to pick out objects in relief and throw the rest into shadow.
However, "religious" here does have a secondary function. A "soutane" is a priest's cassock, which is normally black with a white collar. So in this early light, Smiley finds that Lacon's formal black waistcoat and white collar look much like a cassock. The light is this "religious" because it makes Lacon look like a priest.
